# How to export Anaconda2 PATH in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, path, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I need to `export PATH="/home/fish/anaconda2/bin:$PATH` in the terminal but after I type this I get:

```
>
```

Does not matter what I am typing, I still get a new empty line "`>`"

How can I solve it?

Comment: You missed the terminating `"`, so the shell was reading line after line waiting for you to type it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need the quotes

Try this
export PATH=/home/fish/anaconda2/bin:$PATH